# reacttoolbox input component not validating characters

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, react-toolbox

I am using React-toolbox component Input with type="tel"

How do you prevent the component to not accept invalid characters like alphabets?

I want it to accept only numbers. The input should only be a valid telephone number including international format.

---

Here is a sample code

```
<Input type="Type"
    label="Mobile number"
    name="newUserMobileNo"
    value={this.state.newUserMobileNo}
    className="input mobileno"
    onChange={this.newUserMobileNoChanged}
    error={this.state.noNewUserMobileNo}
    theme={theme} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In onChange function (newUserMobileNoChanged) check event.target.value with number regex(/^[0-9\b]+$/),if its valid then setState of "newUserMobileNo" else not.

```
<Input type="Type"
    label="Mobile number"
    name="newUserMobileNo"
    value={this.state.newUserMobileNo}
    className="input mobileno"
    onChange={this.newUserMobileNoChanged}
    error={this.state.noNewUserMobileNo}
    theme={theme} />
```

Comment: thanks how about the formatting can we do formatting let's say ### ### ### ?

Comment: you can use masking or this package :[react-phone-number-input](http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/)